# Fix group in files/folders on Mac OS X to view in Apache?

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, file-permissions

I copied a directory from a Windows server into the defined document root of my MacBook's installation of Apache. However, the file permissions are wrong. I've tried setting both the user and group to `_www` using Terminal, but the details in Get Info looks a bit wrong.

For example, this is what's currently showing:

[image: What's currently showing]

And this is what works on other files contained in my document root:

[image: What I want]

Why does the files/folders from the Windows server only have two rows in the Sharing & Permissions section? And how can I add `_www` as a group so I (`Martin`) can view and edit files, but Apache (`_www`) can still view and serve them too, like my other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. I ran the following commands:

```
sudo chmod ug+w .
```

This gave a group (which somehow set itself to `_www`) write permissions. Then:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 .
```

This gave me and `_www` read and write permissions, and everyone read permissions.